# reading file java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, arrays, string, out-of-memory

Trying to find a word in a large file. File is read line by line. When reading the way redLine exception is thrown. Are there any way around this? You can read it on the floor as a string?

```
for(String line; (line = fileOut.readLine()) != null; ){
                    if(line.contains(commandString)) 
                        System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
                    count++;
                }
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

UDP:

this is all my bad code:

```
static String file = "files.txt";
    static String commandString = "first";
    static int count = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        try(BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Cp1251")) ){


            for(String line; (line = fileOut.readLine()) != null; ){
                    if(line.contains(commandString)) 
                        System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
                    count++;
                }





            System.out.println("before wr close :"  + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            fileOut.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a `for` loop. But anyway, what is `fileOut`, how is it defined and opened? Where does the file come from, and are you sure it's properly broken into lines and not a data/binary file?

Comment: You should show us the stack trace, as well as supporting code related to the line where the error occurs. The loop you've provided shows that the line field is overwritten repeatedly, which would not result in OOM.

Comment: Why don't you break the for loop when found the commandString?

Comment: @RealSkeptic its opened file: `BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)` . The file is plain text. Today I spent the whole day out to try to read a file character by character. But it has brought me more problems than solutions. Can readLine () to read large files? He's first loads the string into memory and then outputs, so when reading large rows it will fall? Please give an example of how to read a large file or explain. Thank U

Comment: Um, no. Don't give lengthy information in comments. Add it as an edit to your original question, properly formatted (though you can draw someone's attention using a comment). Comments are a bad place to put code.

Comment: Check that the context has no leaks: especially when repeated. That the fileOut is **closed**. That fileOut is a BufferedReader of sufficient large size (64*1024). The file seems to contain no line endings or large lines.

Comment: @Chong I need to go through the file and find the line where lead is found `commandString`. How can I save memory here?

Comment: @JoopEggen the problem is that I do not know how to read large files. As you can read the entire row if it large in size and it is first loaded into memory and then searches the right word in the line.

Comment: Your file seems to either have no line breaks or have very large lines. Are you running this on Linux? If so, can you run `wc files.txt` and add the result to your question?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no, i use windows. I create file in cmd `fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>` file size 5gb

Comment: fsutil creates a file with no actual data. Does this program actually have a purpose?

Comment: @RealSkeptic task was this: output a string that contains a word that we have set. I first made through the `readLine ()` but I was told that if the file will be large and there will be only one line then the application will fall. And you have to redo it. I have no idea how to do it and how to alter.

Comment: Well, you should find some other way to generate a one-line text file that actually contains the word you are looking for. And one that doesn't, just for testing. Now the question is - what is the output they are looking for? If there is only one large line, outputting it as the answer is not a good idea. So what do they want as output?

Comment: @RealSkeptic output all line even if it contains only one line. Such a task. Need to implement something like grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for a word, you can read the file bytewise without holding more than a single byte of the file in memory. 
Read byte by byte and every time, a byte is equal to the first byte of the searched word, start a second loop and read the following bytes and check if the next byte is equal to the next byte in the word and so on. 
To give you an example, I have modified an sample to your needs.
I've omitted on the output of the file, because I don't know, if you want to output all lines or only those which contains your keyword and the latter might be as problematic as reading the code line by line.

```
static String fileName = "files.txt";
static byte[] searchString = { 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't' };
static int count = 0;
static long position = 1;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
        byte read[] = new byte[1];
        outerLoop: while (-1 < file.read(read, 0, 1)) {
            position++;
            if (read[0] == searchString[0]) {
                int matches = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < searchString.length; i++) {
                    if (-1 > file.read(read, 0, 1)) {
                        break outerLoop;
                    }
                    position++;
                    if (read[0] == searchString[i]) {
                        matches++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (matches == searchString.length) {
                    System.out.println((++count)+". found at position "+ (position-matches));
                }
            }

        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```